# NetSuite Client Script pulling credit card information

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, client-side-scripting

I have a client side script that I'm trying to get to access the `ccnumber` field on transactions.

I'm using `nlapiGetFieldValue('ccnumber')` which pulls the number with everything but the last 4 digits hidden.

I have been searching the developers guide for a way around this but have not been able to find anything.

Comment: can you try to use nlapiGetFieldValue('ccnumber',true)?

Answer (score 1):

By default, credit card numbers are masked by NetSuite.  You'll will need to open a ticket with NS Support asking to have the ability to have the view full credit card number permission added.  They will ask you to sign some paperwork acknowledging that you're taking on the responsibility for maintaining PCI compliance on your own.

From the NetSuite help file:
`Important: To see unmasked credit card numbers, a user must log in using a role with View Unencrypted Credit Cards permission. Before you can grant View Unencrypted Credit Card permission, an administrator must contact NetSuite Customer Support and provide a signed agreement. NetSuite Customer Support then activates the View Unencrypted Credit Cards permission for your account.`